# how to use if/else statement to replace a value in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
function Get-vmstatus {
    # Sign into Azure Portal
    connect-azaccount
    # Fetch the Virtual Machines from the subscription
    $azureVMDetails = get-azvm
    # Fetch the NIC details from the subscription
    $azureNICDetails = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ? { $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null }

    #Fetching Virtual Machine Details

    $virtual_machine_object = $null
    $virtual_machine_object = @()
      
    #Iterating over the NIC Interfaces under the subscription
        
    foreach ($azureNICDetail in $azureNICDetails) { 
        $azureVMDetail = $azureVMDetails | ? -Property Id -eq $azureNICDetail.VirtualMachine.id
        $vm_status = get-azvm -ResourceGroupName $azureVMDetail.resourcegroupname -name $azureVMDetail.name -Status
        $vm_tags = ($azureVMDetail.Tags.values) -join ';'
        $vmsize = Get-AzVMSize -VMName $azureVMDetail.Name -ResourceGroupName $azureVMDetail.ResourceGroupName | ? { $_.Name -eq $azureVMDetail.HardwareProfile.VmSize }
        $OsDisksize = $azureVMDetail.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        #Fetching the private IP
        $private_ip_address = ($azureNICDetail.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress) -Join ';'
           
        #VM Details export
            
        $virtual_machine_object_temp = new-object PSObject 
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Name" -Value $azureVMDetail.Name
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "VCPUs" -Value $vmsize.NumberOfCores
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Status" -Value $vm_status.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus

        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Memory" -Value $vmsize.MemoryInMB
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Disk" -Value $OsDisksize   
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Comments" -Value $vm_tags
            
        $virtual_machine_object += $virtual_machine_object_temp
    }

    $virtual_machine_object | Export-Csv "C:\Users\mouj\Desktop\Inventory\Final Scripts\VM_details_$(get-date -f dd.MM.yyyy).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force

}
```

After running the script the Status of the Azure VMs are shown as VM running, VM stopped, VM deallocated. Now i want to replace the VM running with "Active" and VM stopped, VM deallocated with "Offline". How can i do with conditional statement or is there any other way to do it ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `Add-Member` to add a `ScriptProperty` - a dynamic property that can reference the value(s) of other properties on the object:

```
$virtual_machine_object_temp | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name State -Value { if($_.Status -eq 'Running'){ 'Active' }else{ 'Offline' } }
```

Now, whenever you look at the new `State` property, it will resolve to `Active` whenever the `Status` property is `Running`, otherwise `Offline`

Comment: Thanks @Mathias. Could you please tell me how can i fetch ip address with subnet mask id  in this script. Like in this format 10.8.5.24/26 ?